# Can the TrueCrypt hash be slowed down?

Tags: truecrypt

I [have read](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12212/764) that [TrueCrypt uses ~2k SHA-1 hashes on the password](http://blog.bjrn.se/2008/01/truecrypt-explained.html).

> The iteration count is part of the TrueCrypt specification and is 2000 for SHA1, 2000 for RIPEMD-160 and 1000 for Whirlpool (because Whirlpool is more advanced and computationally heavy than the two others).

I recall from prior testing that my computer could do well over ~400k per second. For brute force, that comes out to 5ms per password. (The problem is probably much worse because SHA1 was just a part of the Java program I was working on.)

So for an upcoming installation of TrueCrypt I will be doing, can I lengthen the hash function? If so, I could increase the brute force cost by 50 times while only adding a quarter second to the end user wait.

If you would point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Those statements can also be found at http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=header-key-derivation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, TrueCrypt is open-source, so you could get the source and do whatever you want, provided you know how to program. But the TrueCrypt containers (or partitions, etc) would be incompatible with a non-modified TrueCrypt program.

Moving on, the "iteration count" can't be adjusted without programing. It's not a parameter that you can set anywhere in TrueCrypt. *So you can't change it in an upcoming installation of TrueCrypt*. And those documents you mention are outdated, 'cause the [TrueCrypt docs](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=header-key-derivation) says:

> 1000 iterations (or 2000 iterations when HMAC-RIPEMD-160 is used as the underlying hash function) of the key derivation function have to be performed to derive a header key, which increases the time necessary to perform an exhaustive search for passwords (i.e., brute force attack) [7].

So, it's 1000 to SHA-512 or Whirlpool, and 2000 to RIPEMD-160. It doesn't use SHA-1 anymore.

One more point is that the iteration count might seem to be  low, but there's a 512-bit salt with the password. (source: [truecrypt pages](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=header-key-derivation)). That's a very big salt, which prevents rainbow tables (since any pre-computed table would have to begin with 512-bits (64-bytes) passwords).

Of course, salts don't prevent brute-force, since it's not a hidden value. That leaves you with just your password and, perhaps, with a key-file.

--- Edit: the reality about brute-force.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack#Theoretical_limits) has something about the physical limits on a brute-force attack. If you choose a password that has 128 bits of entropy (that is much more than 16 bytes, since printable characters + numbers + symbols don't use the 256 possible bytes values), problably it won't be breakable before the 4th World War.

[XKCD joke](http://xkcd.com/936/) is also mandatory about this subject.

Comment: Too bad, 1000 SHA-512 I think still comes out to under 5ms. ([source](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html), [extrapolation](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+milliseconds+in+512+bytes+%2F+99+megabytes+per+second+*+1000%3F))

Comment: @GeorgeBailey - You think?  You do understand that the likelyhood of a brute force attack being successful doesn't decrease with the number of iterations.  If your password is one where a brute force attack would have success the chances of it being sucessful stay the same.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey take a look at some sites like [this](http://www.lockdown.co.uk/?pg=combi) or [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack#Theoretical_limits), you'll see that long enough passwords are resistant for a very long period. When you know that, creating a good password is better than a poor password with a strong hashing method.

Comment: @Ramhound I think that George is worried that SHA-512 can be computed very fast (true), but strong passwords add more security than strong hash algorithms with weak passwords...

Comment: @woliveirajr - I have two problems with his statement.  The first is he says that "he thinks it comes out to under 5ms" so he isn't even sure and second "5ms" is a LONG TIME for a computer.  There are billions of combinations, if it was a simple process, TrueCrypt would increase the iteration.  In other words he is being  a worry wart for no reason.

Comment: @Ramhound, **You do understand...doesn't decrease** I understand it does not decrease by much, but it *does* mean you can go with 6 bits less entropy than otherwise. Not much, but seems like a good idea given the cost/benefit ratio. (cost<250ms, benefit>50x cost to hacker)

Comment: @Ramhound, **isn't even sure**, Maybe I should have stated it, but I was hoping the security-competent folks on Security.SE would tell me if 5ms/1000 is significantly off base. I am not sure unless I take more time to review, or I hear confirmation from another professional.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey : Hi, don't want to turn this into conversation, I'll edit my answer to add some more information.

Comment: 128 bits? Somewhat pointless. For one thing, I won't be entering that many characters on every boot. But I do like the comic! **:)**